# cant start xamp it gives error message like this

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, lamp

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.5.3a...
/opt/lampp/share/lampp/phpstatus: line 4: /opt/lampp/bin/php: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL ...
XAMPP: Error 127! Couldn't start Apache!
XAMPP: Starting diagnose...
XAMPP: Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP: Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 74: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: source: not found
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 1: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: /opt/lampp/bin/my_print_defaults: not found
/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 1: /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: /opt/lampp/bin/my_print_defaults: not found
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...
XAMPP: /opt/lampp/lampp: line 302: /opt/lampp/sbin/proftpd: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Error 127! Coul
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your installation of XAMPP is broken...

My best suggestion is to forget about XAMPP and install what you need from repositories and, if needed, configure it yourself. This seems to be a good tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04